# Open RMarkdown programatically or with a shortcut in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I can open `R Script` with `Ctrl + Shift + N`. How to use a shortcut to open a `rmarkdown` file immediately in RStudio?

Is there a solution from the command line?

I use Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: That's a question for your OS, not for R or RStudio. Whatever OS you are using, look for "set file associations" for that OS, it's a common-enough thing on every OS that you'll be able to find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a true built in shortcut - but you can navigate with alt as `alt + F + F + M` (in sequence, not at the same time) on Windows RStudio